# Is there a function to adjust font size to make text field width smaller than a given width in actionscript?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, textfield, font-size

Is there a function or property or better way to do what the following code do?

```
var width:int = 20
while (textField.defaultTextFormat.size > 1 && textField.width > width) {
    textField.defaultTextFormat.size--
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method for that. Another way, depending on what you're trying to do, would be to scale the textfield so that it fits within the required width:

```
var scale:Number = targetWidth / textField.textWidth;
textField.scaleX = scale;
textField.scaleY = scale;
```